# implementing smart app banner for non-itunes-app

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, smartbanner

I am trying to leverage the "smart apps banner" feature provided by Apple in one of my iOS apps.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

This app is for a company's internal use and is not submitted to the app store. In such a case, how can I use the "smart apps banner" feature as I will not be having a value for "myAppStoreID". Apple documentation says this is a required field. All I need is the native app to open if installed or provide a link to download the application from the internal app store of the company. However, I want the web browser to detect if the app is installed or not before displaying the banner on the webpage which the "smart apps banner" feature does.

Comment: You can't , Smart banner is designed to only work with the appstore.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the confirmation